# FastReport's Designer: DisplayLabel instead of FieldName

Tags: delphi, fastreport

The FastReport's designer lists all the fields by the FieldName property. In my project, the design of the reports will be done by other people that are not developers and the FieldName sometimes is not a good name. Can I make the field list display the DisplayLabel intead of the FieldName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the fieldname aliases in the DBDataset components provided by FastReport, just double click on it to get the alias manager.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using SQL for getting the data the simplest solution will be aliasing the field names with "AS"

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, if I don't find a better solution I'll have to do that. The problem is that the dataset is already assigned to other visual components so I can't change the field names. The report shares the same dataset. In order to use the aliases in the fields, I would have to open another dataset, I don't want that.